# Error when try to unwrap realm object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have following issue when I try to use data from one of Realm Objects
I have an error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I'm confused because when I try to do it manually on debug console all works fine

> (lldb) print meal?.mealName
>   (String?) $R0 = "Krem buraczany"

I will attach whole code and show you on which line error appear

Realm Object:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Meal: Object {

@objc dynamic var mealID : String = ""
@objc dynamic var mealName : String = ""
var ingredients = List<String>()
var mealDescription = List<String>()
@objc dynamic var kcal : Int = 0
@objc dynamic var preparingTime : Int = 0
@objc dynamic var imageName : String = ""

convenience init(mealID: String, mealName: String, kcal: Int, preparingTime: Int, imageName: String) {
    self.init()

    self.mealID = mealID
    self.mealName = mealName
    self.kcal = kcal
    self.preparingTime = preparingTime
    self.imageName = imageName

}

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "mealID"
}

}
```

Sending data via segue:

```
    @IBAction func ideaForMealButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ideaForMeal", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! IdeaForMeal
    destinationVC.randomMeal = getRandomMeal()

}

func getRandomMeal() -> String {

    var mealsCount = realm.objects(Meal.self).count
    mealsCount += 1
    let randomMealID = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(mealsCount))
    print (randomMealID)

    return String(randomMealID)

}
```

Receiver:

```
//Global Variables
let realm = try! Realm()
var randomMeal : String? {
    didSet {
        let selectedMeal = downloadMealData(mealID: randomMeal!)
        setUIForMeal(meal: selectedMeal)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

}

//Background Operations

func downloadMealData(mealID: String?) -> Meal? {

    let currentMeal = realm.object(ofType: Meal.self, forPrimaryKey: mealID)
    return currentMeal

}

func checkPositionOfTopIngredientsLabel() -> CGFloat {

    let maxY = ingredientsTopLabel.frame.maxY
    return maxY

}

func setUIForMeal(meal: Meal?) {

    mealNameLabel.text = meal!.mealName // Error!
    mealImage.image = UIImage(named: meal!.imageName)
    preparingTimeLabel.text = String(meal!.preparingTime)
    kcalLabel.text = String(meal!.kcal)

}
```

Thanks!

BR
iMat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not related to Realm. It's a very common view life cycle mistake.

Setting `randomMeal` in the destination view controller triggers the `didSet` observer. The observer is going to access an `IBOutlet` which is not connected yet.

A solution is to run the code in `viewDidLoad`

```
var randomMeal = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    if !randomMeal.isEmpty {
        let selectedMeal = downloadMealData(mealID: randomMeal)
        setUIForMeal(meal: selectedMeal)
    }

}
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks